# is this the right way to do this mysql query

Tags: php, mysql

this is my table

[image]

I am trying to get the all the ids under a main category. this works perfect but is it the right way to do

```
    FROM category WHERE (lft >= '$left') AND (rgt <='$right')
```

---

```
    $allcat_ids = array();

    $cat_id =  mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['cat_id']);

    $res = mysql_query("SELECT lft, rgt FROM category WHERE cat_id = '$cat_id'");
    while ($category = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) 
       {
           $left = $category['lft'];
           $right = $category['rgt'];
       }


    $res = mysql_query("SELECT cat_id, lft, rgt FROM category WHERE (lft >= '$left') AND (rgt <='$right')");`
    while ($category = mysql_fetch_object($res)) 
       {

        $allcat_ids[] = $category->cat_id; 

       }
```

Comment: At least one thing is wrong: absolutely no protection against SQL injections.

Comment: @knittl You cannot tell. `$left` and `$right` variables are loaded from the database, so the user can be sure they are ok if he stored it in the right way (i.e. using numeric data types).

Comment: http://www.vbmysql.com/articles/database-design/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql

Comment: @lorenzo-s: [chain based sql injection](http://seclists.org/fulldisclosure/2010/Apr/114)

Comment: @knittl That's exactly what I said. The query is safe 'cause DB loaded variables comes from a numeric data type field. It's impossible to place malicious code in numeric values.

Answer (score 0):

Looks all right.. Except for the `>=` and `<=`; left and right values are supposed to be unique. Does it work?

PS be careful about injection (use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php), with PDO if possible)

Comment: it works perfect but i am not sure if it is the proper way to do